# ejabberd -- Setting nickname on ejabberd does not reflect on Pidgin/Empathy until I log-in-out

Tags: javascript, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I am in the process of developing this javascript chat application, and everything works fine, except when I want to assign a nickname to the new (website visitor) user.

I am just wondering if there is a way to "force" the other IM client, either from ejabberd XML request or ejabberdctl to refresh the visitor's nickname?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement [XEP-0172: User Nickname](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0172.html). This defines many options to propagate nickname changes.

Comment: Thanks bud! There's a Section http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0172.html#message , which does exactly what I needed ;-)